# How can I resolve issue in SOAP API of CRM for Error: Non-whitespace before first tag in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, oracle, api, soap, crm

I am calling CRM SOAP APIs to get data. It is giving following error

```
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
```

I am calling this API from nodejs using request package. Following is the object sent to request method.

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'ORACLE_CRM_URL',
    qs: {WSDL: ''},
    headers: {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'text/xml'
    },
    body: ` <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Body>BODY GOES HERE</soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>`
};

request(URL, options, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
       console('ERROR => ', err);
    } else {
        require('xmljson').to_json(body, (er, data) => {
            if (er) {
                console.log('PARSING ERROR => ', er);
            } else {
                console.log('DATA => ', data);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

This above code gives an error as mentioned about. The response I am getting is not in UTF-8, it's kind of encrypted.

Please help me with this.